# iPhone-like jQuery Text Flipper?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery-based, cross-browser (with support down to IE7), text "flipper" with behavior similar to that on the iPhone.  I think it's an iOS 5 feature - if a text message or other notification comes in while I'm doing something else on the phone, a small horizontal region at the top (full width and maybe 15-20 pixels high) shows up with some text.  After a few seconds, the rectangular region and text "flip" and fade away.

I'd like to do something similar on a web page.  But in addition to the flip/fade effect, I need the text string to change to the next one is a list.  I might have 10 or 20 strings all together - I'd like each one to show up for a few seconds, flip/fade to the next one, then start the entire list again after reaching the end.

Anyone know of a jQuery plugin that does this?

Answer (score 1):

The nearest I can think of is the [Flip! plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip), using the top or bottom options.

Just note that the effect is more like flipping a plane in 3D space. The iOS notifications you're describing visually behave a bit more like there's a "physical" block of the interface being rotated. Not sure I've seen anyone implement it that way yet, especially not with retaining the part being rotated out, if that'd even be possible.

**[EDIT]**
The "turnDown" effect option of the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is more like the iOS notification animation. That plugin is intended for use in situations where you're flipping between *multiple* objects rather than showing a single notification(you didn't really say what you were doing), but the code is well-documented and you can probably pick out the animation effect's routine without too much work for one-off reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Mobile. It's not really a plugin. But it has multiple effects for mobile browsers and it works on modern browser.

http://jquerymobile.com/